# Dynamic transformation pipeline for Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to build a transformation pipeline dynamically and execute on a dataset ? Imagine that I have a dataset ds. I would like to do something like ds.filter.join.join.filter . Now, the pipeline itself and the arguments to the transformations like filter etc will be dynamic ( taken from a user query, imagine an xml or json that describes a pipeline ).

I sense that it would be simple to write something that used plain java reflection to do this. However, I would like to know if there is a better way to do this - something like build a pipeline dynamically and do a ds.execute(dynamicPipeline).

Newbie to spark and have searched reasonably on the internet/forums about this. Any pointer appreciated. Using Spark 2+ and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

*tl;dr* Please don't use reflection. Use a library or the features of the Scala language instead.

For the love of all that is right with the world, please don't use reflection. It is cumbersome to write, which makes reflection code error-prone, and for all that low-level work, you don't even get a performance boost. In fact, it's very much the opposite.

Meanwhile, it's a fairly common to want higher-level pipeline orchestration of all their jobs. For example, you might have a legacy MapReduce job that works, and you want to feed the output sequence files to Spark; the output of your Spark job goes to Hive, where you have legacy Hive queries that work. And so on. There are open-source pipeline tools out there like [Oozie](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-apache-oozie-workflows-to-automate-apache-spark-jobs-and-more-on-amazon-emr/) that can help. Cascading is another, but I don't believe it has Spark support yet.

However, if you like to take a [Suffering-Oriented Programming](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/suffering-oriented-programming.html) approach as I do where you prefer lighter solutions initially and only bring in the big guns when the pain of not having them becomes too much to bear, then perhaps you could leverage the features of the Scala language to solve the problem.

I am not sure what you are hoping to do exactly, but for example, you might have

```
trait Foo {
  def sparkSession: SparkSession
  def pipeline: Dataset[Bar] => Dataset[Baz]

  val ds = sparkSession.read(...).as[Bar]
  val dsAfterPipeline = pipeline(ds)
}

class Driver extends App with Foo {
   val sparkSession: SparkSession = ...
   val pipeline: DataSet[Bar] => DataSet[Baz] = ??? //generate pipeline as needed

   dsAfterPipeline.write.parquet("file.parquet")
}
```

As you can see here, all the work really happens in the `Foo` trait, but that trait demands it be wired into a class that provides a `SparkSession` *and* a function that represents the pipeline. It can be constructed however you see fit in `Driver` so long as it satisfies the contract specified in `Foo`.

This approach decouples the pipeline code from the orchestration, and it also makes things easier to test since you can provide any function that satisfies `Dataset[Bar] => Dataset[Baz]`.

Finally, you can combine this approach with `implicit` classes in Scala (after rearranging a few things) to enrich (or "pimp") the `DataSet` class to add an `execute` function that takes a pipeline however you provide it:

```
object Helper {
  implicit class DataSetOps[Bar, Baz](ds: Dataset[Bar]) {
    def execute(pipeline: Dataset[Bar] => Dataset[Baz]) = ???
  }
}
```

At which point you could do this:

```
import Helper._
sparkSession.read(...).as[Bar].execute(pipeline)
```

where once again `pipeline` is of type `Dataset[Bar] => Dataset[Baz]`.

Again, I have no idea what you actually want to do, but hopefully you can glean some ideas from what the Scala language offers or from the pipeline libraries out there to get what you need.

And above all else to avoid reflection.